# Translate numpy array to string array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to turn my numpy.ndarray into a normal string array in python

i have tried to do this by converting the numpy array via toString although that did not work as intended.

opencvImage is the name of the array

```
import numpy as np

arr = opencvImage
ts = arr.tostring()
aa = np.fromstring(ts)
aa = np.fromstring(arr, dtype=int)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal string array"?

Comment: IIUC, you could use `list(arr.astype(str))`

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  We don't understand what you intend. And we don't know how the result(s) differ from your intentions.

Comment: @hpaulj i wanted to convert it to a list that I could insert into a mySQL database

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [`tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) function

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(type(x)) # output <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
x = x.tolist()
print(type(x)) # output <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tostring` generates a bytestring from the arrays data buffer.  But it does not save any `dtype` or `shape` information.

To illustrate, make a simple 12 integer array:

```
In [24]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [25]: arr
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [26]: ts = arr.tostring()
In [27]: ts
Out[27]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00'
```

See the docs, this is another name for `tobytes`.  You should be able to save this string the `sql`.

But recreating the array requires more information:

```
In [28]: np.fromstring(ts)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[28]: 
array([2.12199579e-314, 6.36598737e-314, 1.06099790e-313, 1.48539705e-313,
       1.90979621e-313, 2.33419537e-313])
```

We need to specify the `dtype`.  Default is `float`

```
In [29]: np.fromstring(ts, dtype=int)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[29]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Paying attention to the warning:

```
In [30]: np.frombuffer(ts, dtype=int)
Out[30]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

But `pickle` might be better.  It preserves dtype and shape information:

```
In [34]: import pickle
In [35]: tss = pickle.dumps(arr)
In [36]: tss
Out[36]: b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x01K\x00\x85q\x02C\x01bq\x03\x87q\x04Rq\x05(K\x01K\x03K\x04\x86q\x06cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x07X\x02\x00\x00\x00i4q\x08K\x00K\x01\x87q\tRq\n(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\x0bNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x0cb\x89C0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00q\rtq\x0eb.'
In [37]: pickle.loads(tss)
Out[37]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

`pickle` actually uses the `np.save` to generate the string.